# Getusermedia "permission denied" error on android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html

I got an application written in HTML5 and Angular which is running on azure with https. In a click event I ask for

.`getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })`

which works well in the browser on a desktop. If I call the website on a mobile browser (Chrome) on my android phone I get the error "permission denied" and it can't access my camera.

Is "getUserMedia" on android not supported?

BR

Comment: Post android version , chrome version also error logs . Is it html5 page or android app with webview.... Look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream . Android browser have no support but you can easy use android webview like chromium frame .

Comment: Gosh, although Camera was allowed in Chrome in the android settings it was blocked for this site for any reason. While browsing the page, clicked on the (i) in the upper right corner and saw the permissions only for this site . As I allowed the camera again it works as expected.